# descent versus ascent direction

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Suppose $f$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$

If  $\langle\nabla f(x), p \rangle$ =0, is $p$ an ascent or descent direction for $f$ at point $x$?

Comment: It's neither one.

Comment: $\nabla f$ itself is a descent direction of $f$ and $-\nabla f$ is an ascent direction

Comment: Do you mean $\langle\nabla f,p\rangle\equiv0$ or $\langle\nabla f(p),p\rangle\equiv0$?

Comment: Good question @Jesus RS. I fixed it.

Comment: @ Famous Blue Raincoat: Neither one? Or we cannot decide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\langle\nabla f(x),p\rangle=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|_{t=0}f(x+tp)$ is the derivative of the restriction of $f$ to the line $x+tp$. Hence being zero means $t=0$ (hence $x$) is a critical point of that restriction. Thus it is endeed a candidate to be ascent or descent direction, but it can be either or none. One needs another dervative to decide.